# Matrice with characters

Tags: c++, matrix

Hi guys I try to print a matrix with characters.I thought like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char a[3][3]={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"};
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
            cout<<a[i][j];
            }
        cout<<"\n";
        }
}
```

What I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The singular of "matrices" is _matrix_. You are trying to print a _matrix_.

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong? What happens?

Comment: `"a"` is a string literal (with type `const char *`), whereas you want a character literal `'a'`.  Also you can use `char` instead of `int` for your matrix.

Comment: The program print just the first character.

Comment: For starters: `"a"` is a string ("a + \0"), `'a'` is a char.

Comment: When posting questions, you should always describe the actual problem. "What am I doing wrong?" doesn't tell us anything. Explain what isn't working - is the output different than expected? Then describe the expected and observed output. Are you getting an error? Then copy-paste the full error message into the question.

Answer (score 4):

You have a 3 by 3 array of `int`s. You're trying to initialise each element of that array with string literals. There simply is no implicit conversion from the type of a string literal (`const char[2]` in this case) to `int`.

If you just want a matrix of characters, then make your array element type `char`. Then you need to use *character* literals with single quotes, instead of string literals.

```
char a[3][3]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'};
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
char a[3][3]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'};
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
int a[3][3]={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"};
```

To:

```
char a[3][3]={{"a","b","c"},{"d","e","f"},{"g","h","i"}};
```

Comment: You have a problem of initializing a matrix of type `char` with C-style strings (`char *`).  You could do this:  `char a[3][3] = {"a"[0], "b"[0], /* ... */};` if you really want to keep the double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing:

```
int a[3][3]={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"};
```

To:

```
char a[3][3]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'};
```

That should get rid of casting characters to ints.

Edit: Changed the double quotations to single quotations

Comment: But there is still that problem of `"a" == {'a', '\0'}`. In other words, a matrix of `char` is initialized with `char *` *(note the asterisk)*.